# Do (back-slashes in) paths need to be escaped?

Tags: php, string, path, escaping, backslash

It is not uncommon to have to put a path to a file or directory in a string in a program or script’s code. This isn’t usually a problem with paths on *nix systems since they use forward slashes which usually does not need to be escaped in most languages, but Windows uses back slashes for paths which usually *do* need to be escaped in most languages.

With C(++), you usually *do* have to escape the slashes of a path in a string because most compilers will emit a warning if you don’t, but I have seen other code, particularly PHP scripts, which do *not* escape them. For example, I have seen countless examples of configuration files containing lines similar to this:

```
static $storageDir = 'C:\webgrind\tmp';
```

Ostensibly you must escape such paths, and I did consider that maybe they were written by people who were not actually using Windows and simply extrapolating configuration data from Linux to Windows without actually testing it, but if that were the case, then the code *should* fail, yet it seems that it often works.

So do you have to escape paths in strings in code? I’m asking mostly about PHP because that’s where I’ve personally seen this happen the most, but I’m open to other/universal answers as well.

Comment: I’m sure I’ve seen them in double-quoted strings as well. I’ll keep an eye out and update the question the next time I see one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes inhibit all escape sequences other than `\\` and `\'`, so there is no need to escape backslashes within them unless it appears as the final character in the string literal.

Comment: you still have to escape if one  happens to be the last character of the string

Comment: Hmm, before posting the question, I tried looking the answer up and part of that search included checking whether PHP treats single and double quoted strings differently (I know some languages do), and I read that it does not. I just checked again and found a page in the PHP docs (the same one I looked at earlier?) that backs up what you guys are saying. I don’t know what happened (a glitch in the Matrix?), but this answer makes sense (at least for PHP). That said, I’m sure I have seen unescaped paths in double-quotes as well, but until I find an example, I will accept this as the explanation.

Comment: @Synetech: You can get away with unescaped paths in double quotes *provided you never form an escape sequence*.

Comment: I don’t know… that seems risky at best; but even then, shouldn’t you get an `invalid escape sequence` warning?

Answer (score 3):

Single quoted strings in PHP do not need the double escaping. Unlike double quoted strings where a lowercase letter behind a singular backslash could spell trouble.

However in single quoted strings, *the backslash still can escape itself*.

```
'abc\\abc' == 'abc\abc'
```

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of paths particularly, forward slashes will do as well

```
'C:/webgrind/tmp'
```